# grep multiple files into one set of data

Tags: grep

lets say i have few files which have structure like

file1.txt

```
apple fruit 
tomato vegetable
```

file2.txt

```
apple red green
tomato green yellow
```

is there a way to grep at once these 2 files (or more) to receive set of data like this one (or similar)

```
apple fruit red green
tomato vegetable green yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [join](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/join.1.html):

```
$ join file1.txt file2.txt
apple fruit  red green
tomato vegetable  green yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `grep` with the pattern and searched files.
Example:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo "test" > a
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo "test" > b
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo "test" > c
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ grep "test" a b c 
a:test
b:test
c:test
```

See the adapted man page: http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+%22pattern%22+a+b+c

See also the full man page: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you would address the multiple file situation in the OP.

Comment: You're right I think I misread his question. I'm confused now, whether I should remove my answer or not.

Comment: If I were you I'd try to improve it. It might be of interest to view the output of `info coreutils 'tee invocation'`